# Сохранение данных в формате CSV | Node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, nightmare.js

Пишу парсер на основе `Nightmare.js` и хочу сохранять данные в формате *CSV* и стал вопрос какой модуль `Node.js` сейчас самый актуальный для решения этой задачи? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Модуль fs )....

Comment: @Дмытрык как же этот модуль поможет сохранить данные в csv?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как заметили в комментах, csv и есть самый актуальный. Для подобных вопросов npm добавили ряд метрик в поиск, такие как популярность, качество, поддерживаемость. Также можете ориентироваться на время последнего релиза, количество загрузок, оформление readme.

И ещё старайтесь запоминать авторов модулей. Модуль от проверенного автора иногда куда лучше самого релевантного.